# Allow wiki pages to be viewed by non users

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

Is there a way with VSTS Wiki for me to build out Wiki pages that can be viewed by non VSTS users? My use case is this, we have an internal team that develops internal products for our company but there are only about 4-5 of us that are VSTS users. We would like to build out some documentation for the rest of our company to see who are not VSTS users. How would I go about doing this or is this not a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the closest you can get is to link a Build definition to the Git repository containing the wiki and use that to publish the wiki to an external webserver. In the [market place there are a number of tasks that can convert the markdown to HTML or Wordpress](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=render%20markdown&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) and then upload it somewhere. This gives you a perfect read-only version of the wiki.

Otherwise, you need to be at least a basic user to view the Wiki contents.

Comment: Thanks I just found that it wasn't implemented as well but this is a good workaround for now.

Comment: For the [Anonymous on Azure Devops Wiki?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314358/anonymous-on-azure-devops-wiki/67115798) question, I shared a [potentially useful and updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115798/418950).