# Anonymous on Azure Devops Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, wiki, azure-devops-wiki

Is it possible to give anonymous access for foreign people to my Wiki Page on my Azure Devops Project?

I've looking to wiki's permissions, but I didn't found a credential like "anonymous" to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael Hagi's answer is correct, there is no Azure DevOps Wiki 'anonymous' access. However, you can add individuals to the containing Azure DevOps Project as 'stakeholder', achieving no-cost, read-only access (as of 4/2021).

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible, I also have asked on Microsoft Boards:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/672051/wiki-anonymous-access.html